# Term reference with filter

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I wonder if it is possible to add a term reference field with just a subset of the available taxonomy terms. Let me explain. I have a taxonomy vocabulary with a structure like this:

```
- term 1
  - term 1.1
  - term 1.2
  - term 1.3
- term 2
  - term 2.1
  - term 2.2
```

Then I will create a specific content type and for that content type I will add a term reference field. Instead of referencing the whole vocabulary, I need to add only the options for, say, branch 2. I need to show options term 2.1 and term 2.2. In Drupal 6, the Node Reference field allows me to pull the options from a View. But this is a term reference field (it pulls the options from a given vocabulary) in Drupal 7.

I just want to avoid creating several different vocabularies, one for each content type, since their subject is more or less the same. In the future, I could take advantage of the fact that I have shared this resource instead of having a series of scattered vocabulary sets.

Comment: Marcos, have you ever achieved desired results with below hints? Asking, because in one content type I need to present a term dropdown only with a specified level depth and started googling around for solutions...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references). At the moment it dosn't have the views limitation on valid values committed but there is an [issue](http://drupal.org/node/945004) with a working [patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/references_views_mode-945004-108.patch) which should allow you to do what you want.